# MongoParseError: Invalid message size: 1347703880, max allowed: 67108864

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

If i don't try to connect to MongoDB everything works perfectly.  but once i add the line to connect to mongo via mongoose, I get this error message: MongoParseError: Invalid message size: 1347703880, max allowed: 67108864
Unfortunately there is little to no useful information online regarding this error.  What is happening?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = 3001;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:3001/yelp_camp_v12D", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true 
});

app.use(cors());


app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
  return res.send("pong");
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("app running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change to:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/yelp_camp_v12D", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true 
});
```

Comment: your solution resolved my issue. Though i have to wonder why you changed the port to 27017?